# How to get all class child types of a type using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a ***class A*** and a ***class B extends A*** i need to find all the class B and other classes that extends A.

Comment: You haven't provided enough information. Are you using sass/less?

Do you have to find all the HTML elements, or just classes in your file, that extend class A?

Comment: @DarkoRiđić what does less/sass have to do with this? (He's not talking about css classes)

Comment: How does one extend a class?

Comment: I'm not sure this is a well formed question.

Comment: @zer00ne it's a new ES2015 thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two aspects to this:

1. Having a list of classes (constructor functions) to check
2. Doing the checks

There's nothing built-in that will do #1 for you, you have to do it yourself. Functions created via `class` are not added to the global object as properties.

Once you have the list, #2 is possible since `class` locks down the `prototype` property on the functions it creates (you can't replace it with something else), you can establish relationships with `instanceof` and `Object.getPrototypeOf`:

```
if (B.prototype instanceof A) {
    // B extends A, directly or indirectly
}

if (Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === A.prototype) {
    // B extends A directly
}
```

That isn't necessarily reliable with the old ES5 syntax, because the `prototype` on normal functions *isn't* read-only.

**Live Example:** *(requires a browser with support for `class`)*

```js
"use strict";
class A {
}
class B extends A {
}
class C { // Unrelated
}

console.log("B.prototype instanceof A? " + (B.prototype instanceof A));
console.log("Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === A.prototype? " + (Object.getPrototypeOf(B.prototype) === A.prototype));

console.log("C.prototype instanceof A? " + (C.prototype instanceof A));
console.log("Object.getPrototypeOf(C.prototype) === A.prototype? " + (Object.getPrototypeOf(C.prototype) === A.prototype));
```